# What does the number in brackets mean when using 'snap install'?

Tags: snap

I am curious about what '(4247)' mean in my example?

```
Download snap "inkscape" (4274) from channel "stable"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number is the **revision number**.

### Versions and revisions<sup>**</sup>

Versions and revisions convey different details about one specific release of a snap:

- **Version**: the version of the software being packaged, as assigned by the developers
- **Revision**: the sequence number assigned by the store when the snap file was uploaded

The version is a string that was assigned to a project by its developers, according to their development practices. It tells the user what content to expect from a snap. The revision is an automatic number assigned by the Snap store, giving the snap it a unique identity within the channel.

Neither the version nor the revision enforce an order of release. The local system will simply attempt to install whatever snap is recommended by the publisher in the channel being tracked.

**Btw 2 useful links to learn snap:**

- https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/basic-snap-usage#0
- https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/advanced-snap-usage#0

---

<sup>** Taken from https://docs.snapcraft.io/getting-started/3876</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Results of `snap info inkscape`:

```
snap-id: tIrcA87dMWthuDORCCRU0VpidK5SBVOc
channels:                            
  stable:    0.92.3     (4274) 177MB -
  candidate: 0.92.3     (4338) 180MB -
  beta:      ↑                       
  edge:      0.92+devel (4265) 192MB -
```

Both the stable channel and the candidate channel have the same version 0.92.3, and to distinguish the snap package of the stable channel from the  snap package of the candidate channel they have two different revision numbers in parentheses to tell you which snap package you are downloading with `sudo snap install inkscape`.